# Reading a part of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a really large csv file about 10GB. When ever I try to read in into iPython notebook using

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

my laptop gets stuck. Is it possible to just read like 10,000 rows or 500 MB of a csv file.

Comment: Take a look at the `iterator` and `chunksize` options to process the file in chunks.

Comment: did you try to read the documentation at all?? [read csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), hint! look at `nrows=`

Comment: @djk47463 It is possible to get random rows using nrows= ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible. You can create an iterator yielding chunks of your csv of a certain size at a time as a DataFrame by passing `iterator=True` with your desired `chunksize` to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
df_iter = pd.read_csv('data.csv', chunksize=10000, iterator=True)

for iter_num, chunk in enumerate(df_iter, 1):
    print(f'Processing iteration {iter_num}')
    # do things with chunk
```

Or more briefly

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('data.csv', chunksize=10000):
    # do things with chunk
```

Alternatively if there was just a specific part of the csv you wanted to read, you could use the `skiprows` and `nrows` options to start at a particular line and subsequently read `n` rows, as the naming suggests.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the meaning of param `iterator` in `read_csv()`. Does it make any difference when we set `iterator = True` (default value is False). I've gg but it didn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a memory issue. On read_csv you can set chunksize (where you can specify number of rows).

Alternatively, if you don't need all the columns, you can change usecols on read_csv to import only the columns you need.

Comment: Unless you provide an example, this is more of a comment and what you have said here matches exactly to what @Mitch already answered...